# Nil error after choosing picture in iPad (works on iPhone)

Tags: ios, ipad

My app is getting rejected from iTunes because of issues with the iPad, using the camera, when I use the photo library.  For some reason, it crashes in the didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo method.  It works fine with the iPhone, but I'm not sure why it doesnt work on iPad.

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

    if(picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
    {  
        //Crashing here -> "fatal error: unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value"
        var selectedImage: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage

        appraisalPic.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
        appraisalPic.image = selectedImage

        self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)


    }
```

[image]

Comment: I think you should check `if UIImagePickerController.isSourceTypeAvailable(.PhotoLibrary)` before presenting the image picker.

Comment: Also check the syntax, it should be `func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) { 
    ...
    }`

Answer (score 2):

Use given below code instead of above, it's might be Help you.

```
  func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {

            if(picker.sourceType == UIImagePickerControllerSourceType.PhotoLibrary)
            {  

               let url: NSString = info[UIImagePickerControllerReferenceURL] as NSString
               var imageName:String = url.lastPathComponent       
               let nsDocumentDirectory = NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory
               let nsUserDomainMask    = NSSearchPathDomainMask.UserDomainMask

               if let paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(nsDocumentDirectory, nsUserDomainMask, true) {
                  if paths.count > 0 {
                    if let dirPath = paths[0] as? String {
                    let readPath = dirPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent(imageName)
                    var pickedimage = UIImage(CGImage: UIImage(contentsOfFile: readPath)!.CGImage, scale: 1.0, orientation: .Up)
                    appraisalPic.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor();
                    appraisalPic.image = pickedimage
                }
            }
      }
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

The crashes occurs because you are forcing unwrapping of an optional value on following line:

```
var selectedImage: UIImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as! UIImage
```

Try rewrite your code as follows:

```
func imagePickerController(picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [String : AnyObject]) {

    guard let selectedImage = info[UIImagePickerControllerOriginalImage] as? UIImage where picker.sourceType == .PhotoLibrary else {
        return
    }

    appraisalPic.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()
    appraisalPic.image = selectedImage

    self.dismissViewControllerAnimated(true, completion: nil)
}
```

BTW: Are you setting `picker.sourceType` correctly?

```
let picker = UIImagePickerController()
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // ...
    picker.sourceType = .PhotoLibrary
    // ...
}
```

Also read [GitHub's Swift Style Guide](https://github.com/github/swift-style-guide), especially [Avoid Using Force-Unwrapping of Optionals](https://github.com/github/swift-style-guide#avoid-using-force-unwrapping-of-optionals).

Answer (score 1):

On the iPad you have to present the image picker using presentViewController

Here is my Obj-c code for presenting on both iPhone and iPad.

```
-(void)userPhotoLibrary{
    UIImagePickerController *p;
    p = [[UIImagePickerController alloc]init];

    if ([UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary]) {
        [p setSourceType:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary];
        [p setDelegate:self];
        p.allowsEditing = YES;

        [self presentViewController:p animated:YES completion:nil];
    }else{
        NSString *alertTitle = NSLocalizedString(@"NoPhotosAlertTitle", @"The photos are not available title");
        NSString *alertMessage = NSLocalizedString(@"NoPhotosAlertMessage", @"The photos are not available message");
        NSString *alertContinue = NSLocalizedString(@"NoPhotosAlertContinueButton", @"The photos are not available continue button label");
        UIAlertController *alert = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:alertTitle message:alertMessage preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
        UIAlertAction* defaultAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"OK" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                              handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
        UIAlertAction* cancelAction = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:alertContinue style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action) {}];
        [alert addAction:defaultAction];
        [alert addAction:cancelAction];
        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

    }

}
```